# How to do something like with @include sass

Tags: css, sass

I dont want use mixins to define my properties. I want something that build something  between @extend / @include, like the example below

**file => structure.scss**

```
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**file => color.scss**

```
@import 'structure.scss';
.box{
    @extend .box;
    background: red;
}
```

**output:**

```
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.box{
    background: red;
}
```

**I want without mixins:**

```
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be without mixins?

Answer (score -1):

No imports..

```
.bg-red {
    background: red;
}
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    .bg-red;
}
```

or

```
.box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.red-box {
    background: red;
    .box;
}
```

or

```
.square {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.bg-red {
    background: red;
}

.red-box {
    .square;
    .bg-red;
}
```

it's still a mixin. btw this is LESS syntax, sass/scss syntax should be similar

or just use OOCSS `<div class="rounded red box"></div>`

Comment: In LESS, `.box { .bg-red }` is the equivalent of using a mixin in Sass.

Comment: Not only is it not possible for him to get around using mixins, the syntax he's proposing is even larger and more tedious than mixins. The closest solution I see is to write partial pieces of CSS that can be used individually, as mixins, and as oocss at the same time.